# Обработка ошибок Telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Как осуществить обработку ошибки?
Есть такой набросок.
Если приходит текст, а не фото, из функции, то отправить этот текст ?

```
try:
    bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id,get_scrin(x))
except "error_code":400:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,get_scrin(x)
```

Comment: В `except` пишите то исключение, которое желаете обработать. Если его фактически не существует, то создайте сами и возбуждайте по некоторому условию с помощью `raise`.

Answer (score 0):

Вчера решил вопрос данным способом.

```
try:
    bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id,get_stuff(message.text.title()))
except ApiException:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'smth')
```